# Affect of router on internet connection

Tags: router, internet, internet-connection

So I have a internet connection via a network socket in my room I often have a router connected to it because I have multiple devices that need wired internet connections. However when I am using one device only and need to download a lot of data I bypass the router. My question is does bypassing the router actually increase the speed and to what extent this will affect my performance?

Comment: Router performance will affect the maximum upload/download speed when doing NAT (translating between the external ip addres and the internal network ip address). This can become noticeable when the isp provides high speeds: e.g. at 1Gb/s some routers will not be able to keep up. To see whether this affects you, I'd try a speedtest with and without the router between your pc and the isp's connection.

Comment: I question wherever the presence of NAT in itself will cause a slow down. Yes, it's possible the router will not be up to ability to process data passing through it fast enough, but it will be capped at either 100mb/s or a gig/s depending on the device and the internal processor will be specked to cope with that rate.

Comment: @Darren It's not like that: the internal switch can usually be trusted to do 100Mb/s or 1Gb/s (between internal devices) as specified, but address translation between the external and internal address is a different thing.

Comment: Well, like I said; I don't believe NAT in itself could affect speed. Can you offer any citations?

Comment: I found [this link](http://dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/DD-WRT_on_R7000)

Comment: @Darren: Higher-grade routers can offload the actual _routing_ (i.e. route lookup) to hardware. Modifying packets, however, usually requires pushing them up to the slow main CPU...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it a router or a switch? Not that it really matters, but I'm assuming you are on some kind of campus and even if you are using a router, you're only actually using it as a switch.

The answer to your question is "it depends". For example, if you have a gigabit internet connection but your switch only supports 100mb/s then yes, you are going to be downloading things at a slower rate than the maximum possible.

The speed could also be affected by other devices connected to the switch also downloading data over the Internet connection.

Also, your device could be (but, in 2017, is extremely unlikely to be) a hub rather than a switch. In that case, other devices just talking to each other across the hub could limit the speed of your downloads another device.

So, if nothing else is using your internet connection at the same time, and the switch supports connections at least as fast as your internet connection, then no, connections through the switch will not affect your download speeds.

However, having an extra device in line may increase the latency of your connection, but only negligibly.